# Evernote - extra whitespace at end of line when pasting

Tags: evernote

I'm new to Evernote, and really like it so far.  One really annoying bug is that if I paste anything into a note, an empty space gets inserted at the end of each line.  This happens no matter where I copy/paste from.  I've tried it in Notepad, Notepad++, Firefox.  I've reported this as a bug to Evernote.

My question really is - does anyone else get the same problem?  Has anyone found a way around it (other than ignoring the extra whitespace)?

I want to use Evernote for code snippets - so I'd be pasting from Evernote.  I don't want to be pasting extra spaces into all my code.  So for now, I can't use this for code snippets.  Shame, as it would work really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - it turns out that using the OS global "clip current selection" keyboard shortcut doesn't produce this bug.  So I can do that instead of using copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this now seems to be fixed in Evernote 4.